# Return redirecttoaction already but still Not all code paths return a value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need a functions like this, but it's not have right syntax. So how do I fix this error if I want to hold all the meaning of my function?

```
public ActionResult Permission(long? id)
    {

            if (id == null)
                throw new ApplicationException("Không có mục này. Bạn hãy chọn mục khác!");
            Shipping shipping = ShippingRepository.RetrieveById(id.Value);
            if (shipping == null)
                throw new ApplicationException("Không có mục này. Vui lòng chọn cái khác!");
            User _user = null;
            _user = UserRepository.RetrieveByUserID(shipping.OwnerId);
            if (DateTime.Now >= _user.Profiles.AccExpriedDate)
                Acc_Payment(_user.UserId);
            else 
                return RedirectToAction("Details", "Shipping");

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not returning a value in the block below.

```
if (DateTime.Now >= _user.Profiles.AccExpriedDate)
{
    Acc_Payment(_user.UserId);
    //return an ActionResult here
}    
else 
    return RedirectToAction("Details", "Shipping");
```